# angularJS, prerender.io and ZF2: testing locally returns 304 access forbidden

Tags: angularjs, zend-framework2, rerender

I am a n00b with this stuff, I am trying to set up a testing environment for prerender.io.
I've downloaded prerender here: https://github.com/prerender/prerender.git and I've run this from the commandline:

```
$ npm install
$ node server.js
```

I read the documentation here: https://github.com/zf-fr/zfr-prerender

Instead of:

```
return array(
    'zfr_prerender' => array(
        'prerender_url' => 'http://myprerenderservice.com'
    )
);
```

I did this:

```
return array(
    'zfr_prerender' => array(
        'prerender_url' => 'http://localhost'
    )
);
```

This is my angular router:

```
var ListerApp = angular.module('ListerApp',[
    'ListerAppFilters',
    'sharedFactoryApp',
    'sharedServiceApp',
    'ListerAppController',
    'infinite-scroll',
    'angular-inview',
    'ngRoute',
    'itemsReady'
]);

ListerApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    $routeProvider
        .when('/list/:page?',
            {
                templateUrl : '/assets/services/partials/list.html',
                controller : 'ListerCtrl',
                reloadOnSearch : false,
                js : ['/assets/min/shoplist_js.min.js', '/assets/min/bootstrap-typeahead.min.js'],
                resolve : {
                    sharedServiceAppData: function($sharedData){
                        return $sharedData.promise();
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        .when('/detail/:id?', 
            {
                templateUrl: '/assets/services/partials/detail.html',
                controller: 'DetailCtrl',
                css : ['/assets/min/star-rating.min.css'],
                resolve : {
                    sharedServiceAppData: function($sharedData){
                        return $sharedData.promise();
                    }
                }
            }
        ).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/list/1' });
}]);
```

This url works fine: `http://localhost/shop/api/list`

This url returns "Access Forbidden!": `http://localhost/shop/api/list?_escaped_fragment_=/list`

The error.log contrains:

```
[core:error] [pid 5952:tid 1864] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client ::1:50262] AH00127: Cannot map GET /http://localhost/shop/api/list?_escaped_fragment_=/list HTTP/1.1 to file
```

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""

RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you seeing any console output on the Prerender server?

First, the URL you probably want to use is `http://localhost/shop/api/list?_escaped_fragment_=`

but you probably don't want to prerender an API call. That should really probably be `http://localhost/shop/list/1?_escaped_fragment_=` or whatever your url structure is for an actual page.

Comment: The API url is not really an API on the moment. I've tried the the escaped_fragment key but no luck so far. The console is not ouputting anything...

Comment: Sounds like this is an nginx issue then if it's not even getting all the way through to the Prerender server.

Comment: I've haven't been paying attention, when I start node server.js it outputs: server running on port 3000. So when I do: 'prerender_url' => 'http://localhost:3000/public/assets/services/prerender' the console returns " got 200 " etc. etc. Now I have to find out how I can access the rendered shizzle via PHP. I use https://github.com/zf-fr/zfr-prerender and the documentation isn't really telling me how I retrieve the content, it says: "Check from your cache if you have already the content"

Comment: The real trouble I got now is that it outputs strange characters

Comment: feel free to email me at todd@prerender.io. Happy to help more

Comment: You are the man, is see it a little late, but you're the prerender guy yourself. Thanks for being so helpfull